# Firefox strange input cursor shape

Tags: firefox

I'm using firefox 41.0.1 on windows 7 x64 and I have the cursor of the input text with a strange shape I've never seen before.

[image]

How can I restore the default cursor shape ( | )?
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This cursor shape indicates you have (the option to do) bidirectional input - e.g. for writing in Arabic or Hebrew - activated.

#### Resolution:

1. Open your Firefox about:config page
2. Search for "bidi" (without the quotation marks).
3. The first result should be "bidi.browser.ui" with a value of "true"
4. Doubleclick the "bidi.browser.ui" line to change the value to "false"
5. All done, you got your default cursor back.

#### Sidenote:

I am reasonably sure this setting activated when I changed the Windows "Region and Language" Setting "Language for non-Unicode programs" from "English (United States)" to "Arabic (Saudi Arabia)" for troubleshooting something; as that was the only bi-directional input setting I changed before the Firefox cursor changed shape.
Apparently it does not deactivate when you change the setting back to e.g. "English (United States)".